# Calling SSRS report from another report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I an new to working with SSRS and creating reports.

I have created a simple 1 page report from one datasource and 6 datasets.

Report takes one parameter: EmployeeId -- and generates 1 page report for that employee.

So far all good!!

Now, I want to create another report which takes a DepartmentId. This report should generate report for all x number of employees in the department and have x number of pages.

Is there any way I can reuse the report I created earlier (the one with EmployeeId as parameter) to generate the later report I described?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use a subreport, if the DepartmentId is available per Employee (i would assume it is) then that would probably be your best bet

Comment: Could you please refer me some good links to start with subreports?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348%28SQL.100%29.aspx is one place, just Google it or play around with the subreport option in the ide its not that hard to use

Answer (score 0):

How about you inclue the employees department ID on the detail report for the Employee, then you put an action on this field and set as target the department report. Passing the clicked Department ID to the department report and you got a nice solution.